# Работа с таблицей HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как внутри ячейки создать столбец? Пример на картинке со строкой Present

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn48L.png]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: изучайте colspan/rowspan

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы объединять ячейки, в HTML есть два атрибута: rowspan (для объединения по вертикали) и colspan (для объединения по горизонтали). Для того, чтобы объединить ячейки в ASPECT, стоит воспользоваться таким кодом:

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><th colspan="2">ASPECT</th></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2">Meaning</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2">Period of time</td></tr>
  <tr><td rowspan="3">Present</td><td>+</td></tr>
  <tr><td>?</td></tr>
  <tr><td>-</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2">Other</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Хм.. Вроде у меня то же самое...

Comment: Дело в том что когда я использую rowspan, у меня остальные колонки сдвигаются, а мне надо чтобы внутри Present появилась еще одна колонка, а остальные оставались на месте

Comment: О том, как правильно использовать атрибуты, лучше почитать в документации, ведь о том, в каком направлении двигаться, теперь известно. Но я хотел бы обратить внимание, что проще будет понять эту тему, если представить, что столбец ASPECT изначально уже был разделён надвое и состоял из двух ячеек, поэтому при использовании colspan мы объединяем существующие ячейки и если в какой-либо из строк мы хотели бы указать обычные ячейки, то указывать их две.

Comment: Другими словами, если у нас есть один столбец с двумя строками, в одной из которых указан атрибут colspan со значением 3, то на следующей строке следует создать 3 ячейки, чтобы компенсировать наличие colspan

Answer (score 1):

```css
table, tr, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  min-width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

table table {
  margin: -1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>1.1<td>1.2<td>1.3</tr>
  <tr><td><table>
    <tr><td rowspan=3>2.1<td>2.1.1</tr>
    <tr><td>2.1.2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2.1.3</td></tr>
  </table><td>2.2<td>2.3</tr>
  <tr><td>3.1<td>3.2<td>3.3</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table, tr, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td colspan=2>1.1<td>1.2<td>1.3</tr>
  <tr><td rowspan=3>2.1<td>2.1.1<td rowspan=3>2.3<td rowspan=3>2.3</tr>
  <tr><td>2.1.2</tr>
  <tr><td>2.1.3</tr>
  <tr><td colspan=2>3.1<td>3.2<td>3.3</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо всем большое

Comment: @Ahmed_08, тогда прими тот ответ, который помог больше всего.